# Washing machine electricity

Tags: electrical

i have Samsung washing machine from UAE, the cord is without plug, when i moved to the UK I bought the plug and found that it is fitted with a 13 amp fuse

My washing machine has the following label :
 220-240v
2000- 2400w

And i found the instructions in the manual is to plug the power cord into an AC 220 V/ 50 Hz/ 15A wall socket or higher

Will there be a problem connecting the cord to this 13 amp fused plug and then to the wall socket in the UK?

Comment: What model is the washer?

Comment: From [something I found](https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/united-arab-emirates/) there are also 2.5 A sockets available in UAE. They would not be suitable for the washing machine, so they have to say to plug it into a different type of socket, i.e. one which is capable of supplying 10 A, which a 15 A socket is.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason for a washing machine to use that much electricity unless it's heating the water.

If it's heating the water, it's using a resistive element.  With those, if voltage changes a certain percentage, power drawn changes by the square of that percentage.  So looking at the specs, it is 2000W at 220V and 2400W at 240V.  The new voltage is 109% of the old, square that and you get 119%.  The new wattage is 120% of the old.  Close enough: it is behaving like a resistive element.

2400 watts at 240V, that is 10 amps, which is obviously under 13 amps by a margin.  You should be fine.